# How do I add structure to UI built on Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I build an app, which consists of Activity and Fragments, which reside in the Activity. 
I replace Fragments according with the app flow, but it seems that as more actions are added to the app, it becomes more hard to keep track of the app flow in code.

Suppose this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        private enum AppState {
            WAIT_SIGN_IN, SCAN_PERSONAL_ID, CONFIRM_ORDER, PICK_ITEM, NAVIGATE_TO_ITEM
        }

        private AppState currentState = AppState.WAIT_SIGN_IN;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            setWaitSignInContent();
        }

        //Hardware key is pressed
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            switch (currentState) {
            case WAIT_SIGN_IN:
                setSignInContent();
                currentState = AppState.SCAN_PERSONAL_ID;
                break;
            case PICK_ITEM:
                handlePickItem();
            default:
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        //Callback from barcode scanner
        @Override
        public void onCodeScanned(String code) {
            switch (currentState) {
            case SCAN_PERSONAL_ID:
                if (checkPersonalId(code)) {
                    setSignInSuccessContent();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        private void setSignInSuccessContent() {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_primary, fragment).commit();
        }


        private void setSignInContent() {
            Fragment fragment = new ScannerFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_primary, fragment).commit();
        }

        private void setWaitSignInContent() {
            Fragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_primary, fragment).commit();
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, this state-based flow is hard to follow. Any suggestions on how to improve that?

Answer (score 0):

i'm follow this way to replace fragment

create method in your activity for adding and replacing.

```
public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean animate,
        boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (animate) {
        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_from_right,
        // R.anim.fragment_from_left, R.anim.fragment_from_right,
        // R.anim.fragment_from_left);
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

// remove all fragments from the stack
public void removeAllFragment(Fragment replaceFragment, boolean animate,
        boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    manager.popBackStackImmediate(null,
            FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    if (animate) {
        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
        // R.anim.slide_out_left);
        // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_from_right,
        // R.anim.fragment_from_left, R.anim.fragment_from_right,
        // R.anim.fragment_from_left);
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, replaceFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

now override in Fragment

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;

    }
}
```

now just call in fragment for replace like

```
mainActivity.addFragments(new BusinessDetail(), true, tr, null);
```

enjoy i hope it helps.

Comment: The question is: there are multiple places where activity state is changed in my Activity. And it to have transparent app flow.

Comment: mentioned application flow then

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be only one activity in your app, you migh consider using the singleton pattern (the activity itself being that singleton, obviously). For example, your interface may look like this:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean replaceTopFragmentInStack);
public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment); 
public void removeFragment(int index);
public void removeTopFragment();
public void clearFragmentStack();
```

Not only you will be able to easily control the flow, but you will also have access to these methods from anywhere in the app via something like MainActivity.getInstance().removeTopFragment()